# python-oauth2 on python 3x and windows

Tags: oauth, python-3.x

I want to setup an oauth library for Python on my windows desktop. I am newbie and this is my second day on Python and I having a tonne of trouble.

I downloaded the python-oauth2 (hudson-python-oauth2-167.zip) from github. I have extracted this to my python32 folder. When I run the setup command "python setup.py", I first got a syntax error on the print statement. I assumed it is because I am running on windows and so I changed it and then ran the setup.

I then got the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\simplegeo-python-oauth2-1920657\setup.py", line 2, in 
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Can someone guide me with setting up python-oauth2? Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), which is a fork of setuptools that supports Python 3.

That said, your syntax error was because python-oauth2 doesn't seem to run on Python 3 yet, so you need to either help port it, or use Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks. Do you recommend that I shift development to Python 2.7? I am developing a personal app to curate links from twitter. I am finding that several libraries are not compatible with 3x.